# If $f$ is continuous by $x$, and the derivative by $y$ is bounded, $f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Here is my problem..I don't know how to start.

$f$:$\Bbb R^2$$\to$$\Bbb R$.
If $g_{y}(x)$ = $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $x$ for each $y$, and suppose that there exist $M>0$ such that $|f'_{y}(x,y)|<M$, **show that $f$ is continuous at $\Bbb R^2$**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $(x,y)$ and consider the point $(x+h_1,y+h_2)$.
Then write
$$
 f(x+h_1,y+h_2) -f(x,y) =  f(x+h_1,y+h_2) - f(x+h_1,y) + f(x+h_1,y)-f(x,y).
$$
Now $|f(x+h_1,y+h_2) - f(x+h_1,y)|$ can be made small due to the boundedness of $f_y'$,
while $|f(x+h_1,y)-f(x,y)|$ can be made small due to the continuity of $x\mapsto f(x,y)$.

Comment: Thank you.
Can you expand how it actually proves that f continuous?

Comment: The proof then should go like this (you still need to fill the gaps): Take $\epsilon>0$. Then there is $\delta_1>0$ such that $|f(x+h_1,y)-f(x,y)|<\epsilon/2$ for all $|h_1|<\delta_1$. Then there is $\delta_2>0$ such that $|f(x+h_1,y+h_2) - f(x+h_1,y)|<\epsilon/2$ for all $h_2|\le \delta_2$.

Comment: It's like Lipschitz continuity?